# Speed up permutation

Tags: python, performance, permutation

I have next task.

Given integers `n` (`1 <= n <= 1000000`) and `k` (`1 <= k <= n`).

It is needed to find any permutation `p` of integers `1, 2, 3, ..., n` such that absolute difference between each two consecutive integers in permutation is `>= k`, i.e. for permutation `p` is needed `abs(p[i] - p[i + 1]) >= k` for all `i`.

If no such permutation exists for given `n` and `k` then output `Impossible`.

Original online task is in Persian language, that's why I don't provide a link.

I've implemented next code. But it is very slow for solving above task. How can I improve its speed?

```py
from itertools import permutations

n,k=input('').split(' ')

n=int(n);k=int(k)

def check(n,k):
    n=list(n)
    N=n[:]
    result=[]
    b=n.pop(0)
    while n:
        if abs(b-n[0]) >= k:
            result.append(True)
        b=n.pop(0)
    if len(result)+1 == len(N) and all(result):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def solver(n,k):
    return (i
        for i in (permutations(range(1,n+1)))
        if check(i,k)
    )
try:
    aaa=next(solver(n,k))
    for i in aaa:
        print(i,end=' ')
except :
    print("Impossible")
```

Comment: I've had to remove loads of whitespace from the code to keep it readable. Please check whether this still matches your code logically.

Comment: Can you clarify what your speed goal is? There are *huge* performance blunders in that code, e.g. destructively iterating a list, copying an entire list just to preserve its length, and checking an entire list even when it has been rejected already. Have you tried any optimisations so far? Do you actually want to optimise the permutation, or just the solver?

Comment: actually , this is a math problem. in this program there is a list of numbers from 1 to n and i have to sort this list in a way that every two numbers in a row have at least (k) difference. For example if i have such this list [1,2,3,4,5] =》 this program have to give me a list like this [1,3,5,2,4] . You can see that 1 and 3 have 2 unit difference. (abs(1-3)=2) and abs(3-5)=2 and abs(5-2)=3 (at least k=2) and abs(2-4)=2. Because this problem mathematicaly hard for me then i choose permutation.

Comment: @mohamadmahdi I think I've solved your task for large `n` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64264557/941531). Read whole answer text.

Comment: @mohamadmahdi A math problem always will be fastest to solve by exhausting its mathematical properties. My question is whether you care about the current approach which does *not* exhaust these properties to simplify the approach, or whether an entirely different approach is in scope as well.

Comment: By the way, this looks like a coding challenge task. Please link to the task if that is the case. Either way, please clarify the actual task – it is currently not clear how ``n`` is actually to be used. The code suggests that a list of ``n`` consecutive numbers is to be permuted, but the question does not say so.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Somebody closed the question as needing more details. I've edited it to provide more details. How can I un-close the task? Probably more reputation is needed to un-close. Details are provided according to long conversation with author about details of the task.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but it seems as if the sequence ``0, n/2+1, 1, n/2+2, 2, ..., n/2-1, n`` given ``n > 2*k`` always satisfies the requirement, and no sequence given ``n <= 2*k`` can satisfy the requirement (give or take off-by-one errors on the bounds). There seems to be no reason to brute-force every permutation.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, you're seems to be right. So it is not very difficult mathematical task. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64264557/941531) is just a bit more complex solution, also with also easy sequence. BTW, what about un-closing task? Does the task have enough details to be un-closed?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In my solution I found that task can be also solved for all `n >= 2 * k - 1` so for your solution you also have to think about solving cases when `n == 2 * k - 1` and `n == 2 * k`.

Comment: @Arty As said, off-by-one is possible. At a glance, the sequence ``0, n/2+1, 1, n/2+2, 2, ..., n/2-1, n`` also works given n >= 2*k and is for the ``n`` even case; for the uneven case, dropping the last element is fine. In other words, it should work for ⌊n/2⌋ >= k.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, you're right, your sequence suits perfectly well, plus extra few corner cases have to be solved separately. In my solution I use sequence `0`, `k`, `2 * k` ... until `n`, then `1`, `k + 1`, `2 * k + 1` until `n`, then `2`, `k + 2`, `2 * k + 2` until `n`. Also simple sequence like yours implemented in two lines of code. Still as yours same is mine doesn't solve corner cases, so I had to solve extra few cases separately in my code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi BTW, do you know how can I see who has closed the question? So that I can inform that person that I've added a lot of extra details to the question, so that it can be now un-closed!

Comment: @Arty Reopening is not tied to the people that voted to close it. The question is queued for reopen review already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of cause simplest optimization is to improve `check(...)` function by using very popular [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) library, just install `NumPy` one time before using next code through `python -m pip install numpy` command line.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDBboMwDL3zFVYvJBpCQ711ovd9RgrOagFOlJipfD1zYUOV5kvs5/eeHcdF7oHP60pTDEmA5yku4DJwLHwKE5BgkhDGDL@MiGmaxQkFzkXB1dASx1lMWdo6x5E0g9JqR3ExbD@GLRkU6tFDd8duMCqzlwI0EsqcWMfV7paNPj15rzJbT8TGwrWFYVfmMH5j@i81tFXP8CEBASn2uqVJjr/QNBW/Ndbag01/25BabqgtJC27uXOuZXyIeRm7k44hSrkcZjE9f0kVct9uB8BHh1FgZ@zd06eeMGe6jXiy69q8w/kH)

```
def check(n, k):
    import numpy as np
    return np.abs(np.diff(n)).min() >= k
```

But if solution for your task should be really-really much faster then I implemented full next new solution that should be very fast for large `n` (1 million or even more). Also my next solutions doesn't use any extra library, like `numpy`.

Main solving function there is `solve2(n, k)` it returns list with correct answer (correctness is double-checked by `assert`), or is answer doesn't exist it returns `None`. Example of usage this solving functions is `test2()` function, just for example it creates answers for all small `n` and `k` combinations. If solving functions returns `None` testing function converts it to string `Impossible` before printing.

You have to implement your own variant of `test2()` the way you need for your case, like taking input `n` and `k` from user like you did in your original source code, I just made `test2()` for example of how to use my code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVPBbsIwDL3zFb413YJEQdoBjd132Wk31EMZ7gjN0ioJmzbt35mdQtsUkJZDlNh@z/aL03z7XW0Wx@MWS3C1/sS5MBKqdDkBWqqECh5XkEFtwYRT6@DVwAq0cl7YwryjMGkaXKgJRbEwhztCT8eQl9pgH9gFMXnI0Frux7A143Lymc78ZjyVqmvyziRMs84RClhdpQp061kuac/CPqc9Zqpki5SwkDDroCVpoEAZaPsNVQcU507HKYgyJzoVmckI9yRiZKRq2f5E/cckvDYWi@oGNXVW3aZH7XA5lIR7EkGOtBN70dvi3JXzlCJ4OnvMOIj6x0OxsjeVdH6UnQP2fYCSwEN5ERbJsb9wdXKcZ7kB5cDUPsxgT1U4h9aDRiOalOeGkon2RonTuDuBrYJcInKJTT4mKrQWxcaJkibEpfywVQgvJThG/KhGNOvltJ2/bJnTzwkcFv3BEuNkwt/Ro/NzcWq5DB@wU4QGL3sYqMHuKnKbK49aGPeFlroY/vTrEacDiXY@9cqFQYDk@aOpnVMbjUk8oFYZH7jlCSwBzZZIE4BfgERCqQ9uR4ZXe0Dq/dTp5Hj8Aw)

```
def solve2(n, k):
    if k <= 1 or n <= 1:
        p = list(range(n))
    elif n < 2 * k - 1:
        p = None
    elif 2 * k - 1 <= n <= 2 * k + 1:
        p = [None] * n
        cnt, klo = 0, -1
        if n == 2 * k + 1:
            p[0], p[1], p[2], cnt, klo = 0, k, 2 * k, 3, 0
        for i in range(k - 1, klo, -1):
            p[cnt] = i
            cnt += 1
            if cnt >= n:
                break
            p[cnt] = i + k
            cnt += 1
    else:
        if 2 * (k + 1) <= n <= 3 * (k + 1):
            kst = k + 1
        else:
            kst = k
        p = [None] * n
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(kst):
            for j in range(i, n, kst):
                p[cnt] = j
                cnt += 1

    if p is not None:
        assert len(p) == n, (len(p), n)
        p = [(e + 1) for e in p]
        assert all(abs(f - s) >= k for f, s in zip(p[:-1], p[1:]))

    return p

def test2():
    for n in range(1, 16):
        for k in range(1, n + 1):
            answer = solve2(n, k)
            answer = answer if answer is not None else 'Impossible'
            print(n, k, answer, end = '  |  ', flush = True)

test2()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.but i want to speed this up, the (n) can be 1000000 and this can take lots of time

Comment: @mohamadmahdi Then it is interesting combinatorical/mathematical task. A needs some fast formula to be invented to solve it. Definitely generating all permutations would be to slow, generating permutations is fast enough only below n=10.

Comment: @mohamadmahdi Can you please provide exact full text of your task? Or maybe a link to description? I want to know what exact limits for `n` and for `k` (min and max). Also does it need to be any numbers (like you told in your question) or specifically `permutation` of numbers `1`..`n`? Also does it need to be lexicographically very first permutation or just any random suitable permutation? Or even permutation is not needed at all, and you need just a short answer `Possible` or `Impossible`?

Comment: @mohamadmahdi Would be nice if you give a link to web-site page where original problem/task was located. Interesting task, would be nice to read original whole page text.

Comment: Thank you agin very much for your help.

Comment: @mohamadmahdi How about giving us/me a link to original web-site where you got this problem to solve? Would be great to read the task from original source.

Comment: @mohamadmahdi I think I can solve the task if you give me a link.

Comment: Im sorry ,I try to simply explain the problem: the (n) is a integer number between 1 to 1000000 and the (k) is between 1 to n. At the first step we have to create a list with the number (n) .for example if we have n=5 then owr list is [1,2,3,4,5]  . And now if k=2 then we have to sort this list by the way that every number in the list have at least 2 difference with the next number. Result of program is such this list=》 [1,3,5,2,4] . If you look at the result list you will find out that 1 and 3 have 2 difference. Also 3 and 5. And 5 , 2 (at least 2 difference). and 2, 4 .

Comment: The original link is  in persian language. i'm sorry

Comment: @mohamadmahdi I understood your details. Have few important extra questions - 1) As the answer should you return/print the resulting list itself? Or you just need to print short "Possible"/"Impossible"? 2) Do we need to print any suitable solution? Because there could be millions different correct solutions. 3) Can `numpy` module be used for solving task, as it needs `pip`-installing it? Because if you want to post this code somewhere for online contest they usually don't allow using any extra modules except standard python modules.

Comment: 1)if our list can be sorted then print that . and if there is no way to sort our list then print "impossible".2)only one of them is enough.3)no we can not use numpy.

Comment: @mohamadmahdi OK, I have ideas how to solve your task, I'll post one solution soon.

Comment: @mohamadmahdi I've just updated my answer, added new very fast algorithm for solving your task, read whole my answer for details. I wonder if my solution solves all the cases correctly, at least it solves most of cases correctly, I've checked my responses with brute-force permutations like in your original code and my solution is correct for all combinations of `n` and `k` `<=13`. Waiting for you testing my code!

Comment: it was great and very nice.thank you very much

Comment: @mohamadmahdi Do you mean that my script solved whole task totally correct? Can't be :))) If my solution was useful don't forget to up-vote and/or accept my answer!

Comment: @mohamadmahdi I was just trying to test all different simplest ways to find needed permutation and comparing all my solutions to your original brute-force `itertools`-based solution. Basically main idea is to take numbers `0`, `k`, `2 * k`, `3 * k`, `...` until `n`, after that take `1`, `k + 1`, `2 * k + 1`, `...`, until `n`, after that `2`, `k + 2`, `2 * k + 2`, `...` until `n`. And so on. Very simple variant of solution. It is main last `else:`, other two `if/elif` are just covering remaining corner cases that I found from `itertools` brute force solution.

Comment: @mohamadmahdi BTW, did my solution above correctly solved your online contest problem? Was it online contest problem in fact?

Comment: Hello again.your solution was correct but l dont understand that why it was scored 56 of 100. The error was time limit

Comment: @mohamadmahdi Did it solve all 100% of provided tests? Maybe it solved correctly only half of them? Or maybe the score is given according to number of submissions/trials to solve the task? Or maybe they give score proportional to the position among fastest solutions? E.g. if you sort all author's correct solutions by time spent inside script to solve all tasks then if there are 1000 correct solutions in total submitted then if it is 440th place then it is given `100 * (1000 - 440) / 1000 = 56` score? If you're on 1st place you're given score of 100.

Comment: I just know that the score is according to the right answers in a certain time limit .it was 53 tests and I do not  know what are them really. the website only show that your solution was accepted  in 30 tests and there was 3 wrong answers and 20 time limit errors

Comment: @mohamadmahdi Is it allowed for you to submit solution several times? So that you can increase score. Because there are too many time limit errors, probably they could be fixed by optimizing my code.

Comment: @mohamadmahdi If it is allowed to submit code several times then try [this code here](https://cutt.ly/DgaXJp9), I've just optimized few lines inside the central loop, compare this linked code to the code posted in my answer to see those few lines that are different. This should give good speed improvements.

Comment: it is great ,but has 4 wrong answers and its score is 92 of 100,

Comment: @mohamadmahdi So now there is not Time Limit Exceeding for any tests? Cool! I think wrong answers are due to some corner cases not solved by me. I've solved several but probably some more exist. But 92 score is probably great :).

Comment: of course, thank you for your help very much.

Comment: Im sorry .can you tell me how many years you are working with python?

Comment: @mohamadmahdi Most of my programming experience time I used to do `C++` coding, from my childhood (actually Pascal/Basic in childhood), so it means already like `20` years. And only several last years I started more and more to use Python, both as a job and as a hobby too, probably point of starting using Python is vague, but probably around `3-4` years of intense Python experience I have! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223016/discussion-between-mohamadmahdi-and-arty).